# Given $P^2 + 17^Q = 10^8 $, what is the number of values that $P$ can take?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

$P$ is an integer . $ Q$ is an odd positive integer.

If $P^2 + 17^Q = 10^8$ , what is the number of values that $P$ can take?

Answer (score 5):

There is no such $P$, thus the answer is $0$.

The reason is because $x^2 \equiv 0,1 \pmod {4}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Assume there exists such integer $P,Q$, that $P^2+17^{Q}=10^{8}$, Tten we have that$$P^2=10^{8}-(16+1)^{Q}  \equiv 0-1 \equiv 3 \pmod {4}$$
So $P^2 \equiv 3 \pmod {4}$. Contradiction to the statement above.

You can see this is true no matter the value of $Q$, so the condition that $Q$ is odd is unnecessary.

Comment: But if there was a - instead of a + then it would at least not be impossible for that reason?

Comment: @mathreadler I don't know. There would be a finite amount of $P$ still, I can guarantee that much.